# Testing in rails - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm trying test my controller. When I run the test, in **"should edit user"**, this error appears.

**1) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_edit_user:
ActionView::Template::Error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty**

I'd like how resolve this error

**user_controller_test**

```
    test "should edit user" do
        get :edit, id: @user
        assert_response :sucess
    end
```

**users_controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
    @users = User.all
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.password == @user.password_confirmation
        if @user.save
            upload params[:user][:document]
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render "new"
        end
    else
        render "new"
    end
end

def new
    @user = User.new
end

def edit
    @user = User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token])
end

def edit_password
    @user = User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token]) 
end

def update
    @user = User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token])

    if @user
        @user.update_attribute(:username, params[:user][:username]) 
        @user.update_attribute(:email, params[:user][:email])
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render "edit"
    end
end

def updatePassword
    @userSession = User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token])
    @user = User.authenticate(@userSession.username, params[:user][:password])

    if @user
        if params[:user][:password_confirmation] == params[:user][:new_password]
            if @user.update_attribute(:password, params[:user][:new_password])
                redirect_to root_path
            else
                redirect_to edit_password_path
            end
        else
            redirect_to edit_password_path
        end
    else
        redirect_to edit_password_path
    end
end

def desactivate
    @user = User.find_by_id(session[:remember_token])

     if @user
        @user.update_attribute(:account_status, false)
        redirect_to log_out_path
    else
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

def destroy
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @user.destroy
     redirect_to(action: "index")
end
```

and **edit.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Desativar conta", desactivate_account_path %>
<%= link_to "Alterar Senha", edit_password_path, class: 'button' %>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">    
    <%= f.label :username %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Salvar alteração' %>
</div>


<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two things:

First, for your code to work exactly as it is, try this:

```
test "should edit user" do
  session[:remember_token] = @user.id
  get :edit
  assert_response :success
end
```

*note the spelling of success, two "c"s*

That's because the moment you run your test there is no `session`.

And that brings the second thing: Where are you initialising the `session` hash? You should have something like `session = params[:user]` somewhere in one of your controllers.